# Comparing an object's int variable with a String

Tags: java, arrays, list, casting, compare

I am taking in a String of a movie's release year, and an ArrayList of films (String title, int release year, enum genre etc...). The parameter **String year** is the users input of search which will be compared to each film to find a film that has the matching release year. The matches will be saved into an ArrayList. By keeping the parameters as **(String year, ArrayList films)**, how can I compare each film's year with the user's input of a year to search for? I have tried casting these but was unsuccessful.

```
public ArrayList<Film> compareYear(String year, ArrayList<Film> films)                          
{
    ArrayList<Film> yearMatches = new ArrayList<Film>();
    for(Film f : films)                   //search through ArrayList of films
    {
        int years = f.getYear();         //gets the year for each film and compares it to user input search "year"
        if(years == year) {
            yearMatches.add(f);
        }
    }
    return yearMatches;
}
```

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832 for how you can compre strings

Comment: Convert the string to an int or the int to a string and compare it

Comment: What can I say. What about you *don't* take a year as string, and instead you require year as `int`?

Comment: Also, that method's name should not be `compareYear`, it is `queryByYear` or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Integer.parseInt()` on the string version, to convert it to an integer before doing your comparison:

```
if (years == Integer.parseInt(year))
```

Or you could use `String.valueOf` on the int version of the year, to convert it to a string:

```
if (String.valueOf(years).equals(year))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Integer.parseInt(String value)` to convert a string to an int.
i also noticed that your method returns a non existing list of results (`releaseYearMatches` which has to be `yearMatches`), so i fixed that for you aswell

```
public ArrayList<Film> compareYear(String pYear, ArrayList<Film> pFilms)                          
{
    int year = Integer.parseInt(pYear); 
    ArrayList<Film> yearMatches = new ArrayList<Film>();
    for(Film f : pFilms) {
        if(f.getYear() == year)
            yearMatches.add(f);
    }
    return yearMatches;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Convert the string year to an int year** before comparing. Replace your code block with below code block, hope it will help

```
public ArrayList<Film> compareYear(String year, ArrayList<Film> films)                          
{
    int yearInt = Integer.parseInt(year);
    ArrayList<Film> yearMatches = new ArrayList<Film>();
    for(Film f : films)                   //search through ArrayList of films
    {
        int years = f.getYear();         //gets the year for each film and compares it to user input search "year"
        if(years == yearInt) {
            yearMatches.add(f);
        }
    }
    return releaseYearMatches;
}
```